# Bug: Barrier connected with "percent height" in ConstraintLayout is inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout, android-scrollview, constraintlayout-barrier

I have a `ScrollView` which has a `ConstraintLayout`.

Inside the `ConstraintLayout` I want to position a `View` to the bottom of a `Barrier`.

The `Barrier` itself has constraints: a `Guideline`(it can be also a view with height half of parent) which is **half** of the ConstraintLayout and a `TextView`.

The issue here is that the `ConstraintLayout` will expand even more (adds more scrollable area) because of the half of screen percentage calculation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:background="#39537A4B"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <View
                android:id="@+id/topHalf"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="#99B146B8"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/bottomHalf"
                android:layout_width="10dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:background="#99B89F46"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.5"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Do smth \n\n\n\n\n\n\nasdasda"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
                android:id="@+id/guideline"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />

            <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
                android:id="@+id/barrier"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:barrierDirection="bottom"
                app:constraint_referenced_ids="guideline, text" />

            <View
                android:id="@+id/view"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="#651F7878"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/barrier"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/barrier" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Try changing the `Barrier` constraints to:

```
app:constraint_referenced_ids="text"
```

And you understand that `Barrier` brakes the calculations.

I know how to solve this layout issue from java, I want a solution from xml. It can be this is a bug on `ConstraintLayout`

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is odd and is definitely related to the barrier and a `wrap_content` *ConstraintLayout* Here is a simplified layout that showcases the behavior.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_blue_light"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/redBox"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_red_light"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent=".5" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Barrier
        android:id="@+id/barrier"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:barrierDirection="bottom"
        app:constraint_referenced_ids="redBox,guideline"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

With the above layout, the following is what is displayed. Although the *ConstraintLayout* is `wrap_content`, it expands to twice the height of the red box.

[image]

If we remove the red box or the guideline from the barrier, the layout behaves:

[image]

The height of the *ConstraintLayout* can be varied by changing the location of the guideline. Here it is with the guideline set at 30%:

[image]

The expected behavior, IMO, is that the *ConstraintLayout* would size itself based upon the heights of its child views, here just the red box, and the guideline would be set accordingly. That is clearly not what is happening.

Maybe someone can figure out an XML work-around using the simplified layout. I didn't see a similar issue reported from a cursory search, so it may be worth reporting.

*(Using *ConstraintLayout* version 2.1.0)*